# Is it ok to use shared ObservableObjects in SwiftUI views?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Shared ObservableObject is a convenient way to pass data between views and it seems like it's working for tracking and reacting to changes on published variables.

In terms of SwiftUI design paradigm, is this ok and a valid use of ObservableObject. Are there any downsides? If it is not the correct way, what would be the best way to track changes for views which might have a long parent hierarchy, always pass down the object from parent?

Shared object example:

```
class Obj: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = Obj()
    
    @Published var changed = false
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var obj = Obj.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            obj.changed.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("CHANGE")
        }
    }
}

struct OtherSwiftUIView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var obj = Obj.shared
    @State var text = "HELLO"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onChange(of: obj.changed) { _ in
                text = "BYE"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: For an official explanation on how to manage data in a SwiftUI App (in particular using ObservableObject), have a look this info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: You can use `EnvironmentObject` as well for the long parent hierarchy.

Comment: `EnvironmentObject` is designed for what you describe in the second paragraph of your question so I would say it's a perfect fit. The one main issue or thing to be aware of with a shared class is that it is global to your whole application and not just your views. Why this could seem appealing it could leave to issues with what state it is in, what triggered an update, maybe also concurrency issue, data races etc.

Comment: It's fine but its inefficient compared to simply using let for read access or @Binding for write access when passing in the properties of the object the View needs rather than the whole object that may contain other things the View doesn't need.